# Switch between two 3.5 mm audio jacks

Tags: sound, audio-jack

In my desktop computer, I have two audio jacks. One of these is connected to my speakers and one to my headphones. Windows allows me to set the output to use only either one of these jacks (they appear in Windows sound settings as rear audio jack and front audio jack). In Ubuntu, I can find only one "analog output" which controls both the rear and the front audio jack. Is there a way to control which of these outputs I want to use in Ubuntu?

Comment: are you using unity? I know there is a way or independently controlling them in kde at least

Comment: Typically there is a "headphones" that you can select: https://imgur.com/JedzM5G

Comment: I'm using unity. I don't have headphones option. Only analog, digital and hdmi.